# No internet on Linux Mint 17

Tags: networking, dns, internet

I have been using Mint 17 for the past 2 months now and it didn't show any problem in networking. Recently, however, when I connect to WiFi it works fine for a while, but when I leave the system idle even for a few seconds, the internet goes down but the wifi is still connected.

The browser shows the error `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET` and I have changed the DNS to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` but the problem still won't budge. If I disconnect and connect again, it will work fine but onlly until the next time I leave it idle.

Comment: When the internet is down, what is the output of `ping -c 2 google.com` and `ping -c 2 8.8.8.8` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nano Edit `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

Somthing like

```
 #Generated by NetworkManager
 nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

More example for [Resolv.conf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolv.conf)

Next step type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge resolv.conf
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Reboot

Answer (score 0):

I have been encountering the same exact thing (Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca). Try going in to network settings and disabling IPv6 - if your PC is not able to actually use IPv6, then this can delay the connection. Go to Networks - Newtworking and find your connection - edit with the wrench icon - and disable IPv6. This could also be done in sysctl.conf. There may be other factors causing this - I am working on this very issue.

Comment: I tried that,it didn't work.Thanks for looking into this though.I am also using all my time to solve this.

Comment: Jashan - I tried the solution below from GAD3R - but in my PC, the file name in etc is resolvconf - tried it and so far, so good - I am expecting this purge to work because I think Mint can get confused with hosts and names.

Comment: Ben,the above mentioned thing worked.Maybe it was something that GNS3 altered in my laptop.